# How to get all topics list of Firebase through API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I want to retrieve all the topics created so far via API request, similar to the list that firebase console display. See the image attached.

[image]

Comment: visit this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging
it is list out some topics.

Comment: I am wondering why this was marked as duplicated questions. The created topic list is different to the subscribed topic list from a specific mobile device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no public API to get the list of topics for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere, a reference would be helpful.

Comment: Documentation for a product typically tells you what that product *can* do. A list of all the things a product *can't* do would be rather long.

Comment: Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @HishamMuneer could you give a description of the use-case you face that would be helped by having a "list-topics" endpoint?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I want to display a list of topics out of which user can check/uncheck to opt in.

Comment: @HishamMuneer seems like a reasonable use-case, but since topics are created automatically once your clients subscribe to them, then you can assume the existence of them and let your users opt in (subscribe) and if the topic exists fine, if not it will be created. I get that this is a bit of a work around so I agree that it would be reasonable to have a method to list current topics.

Comment: @ArthurThompson Lets say I have 2 users - userA and userB. And to every user I have to display two options 1. textbox to create a topic, 2. list of already created topics by all users in which s/he can opt in. If userA created a topic "topicX" and userB created "topicY", how can they see each other's topics. Right now I am handling this by maintaining the list of all topics on my own server. Try posting a question on SO and put the appropriate tags, ya I can create a new tag on SO but if SO doesn't show me the list of tags already created by other users, things will go crazy.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just saw that you are an engineer at Firebase, Do you believe my problem of getting all topics list is legit(read the above comment), if yes, when this can be resolved by Firebase?

Answer (score 20):

I just copy Answer from same question here becuase this page is first result in google: [Get all subscribed topics from firebase cloud messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging/37989087)

### you can do it through a GET request

### HTTP GET Request

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<TOKEN>?details=true
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

**TOKEN** in url : `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

**key** : can be found in [firebase console][1]: Your project -> settings -> Project settings -> Cloud messaging -> Server Key

Answer (score 2):

The way I got around this was using the firebase database, first create a topics folder inside the database, then add entries into this folder when a user creates a new topic.

You then create a function within the app to retrieve all entries in this folder within the database.

Now you can allow the user to select a pre existing topic from the results of the database and then use that to call your subscribe function.

Not a solid solution for all but worked for me.