# Google FCM topic Subscriptions after logout/login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when a User X has subscriptions for many different topics like "new feed on his group" or "new answer on a question I wrote", and do later a log-out in the app  (which lead to Token-ID refresh) and logs in after a while, with the new FCM-Token all Subscriptions are lost.

**Edit:** In my App, Token get refreshed in the case, another user logs-in in this device.  **Example**: If the application is uninstalled, and installed again, or user logs-in in another device, then it loose all the data about its past, and I need to re subscribe all the relevant topics

What would be best practice to restore all the topic subscriptions for the certain user. I thought, to save every subscription of the user in a database (mongodb in a seperate collection or redis as list with lua-script) and doing a database checkup for all subscriptions and do new subscriptions for this fcm-token after a login. I use for User/Groups management MongoDB but use also redis.

Also I want the possibility, that a user can subscribe/unsubscribe for for a group, question etc.. (and see if he is subscribed on it).

Comment: if he logs out the token is not refreshed

Comment: in your last edit I have explained it in the answer, if the user uninstalls then yes the token is removed. You need to use method `onTokenRefresh()` and inside of it do this `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather");` that way the token is refreshed and whenever it is executed the user will still be subscribed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is not refreshed if the user logout, as neither authentication nor logging out/in without using authentication matters.

It is refreshed in 4 situation:

> App deletes Instance ID
>
> App is restored on a new device
>
> User uninstalls/reinstall the app
>
> User clears app data

more info about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()

So lets say a user subscribed to a topic called `weather`, then he will have a token ID related to him. If you use `onTokenRefresh()` and add subscription inside that method then when he re-installs the app he does not need to subscribe again.

> Also I want the possibility, that a user can subscribe/unsubscribe for for a group, question etc.. (and see if he is subscribed on it).

The user can easily subscribe doing this:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather");
```

Unsubscribe:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("weather");
```

You can make it simply like this, the user clicks on button subscribe and then he will be subscribed to a specific topic, and another button unsubscribe and he will be unsubscribed and wont receive notifications anymore for that topic (until he subscribes again)

Comment: I understand, but when I call onTokenRefresh() (after App deletes Instance ID) and add  subscription inside that method, from where do I get the topics on which the certain user was subscribed? 

Example: If the application is uninstalled, and installed again, then it loose all the data about its past, and I need to re subscribe all the relevant topics.

Comment: currently you cannot do that, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874606/how-to-get-all-topics-list-of-firebase-through-api .

Comment: Ok, then the only possibility would be, to save topics for a certain user in a databse-store to retrieve.

Comment: @BestPractice2Go yes but honestly I do not see the point, as the user on his device can only unsubscribe as you can see from the answer the topic is related to the token which is also related to the device, thus only the user can subscribe or unsubscribe from his device. If an admin exists he cannot stop the user from receiving notification

Comment: Yes you are right, but when the user login into another device, he wants to get notifications for all topics he did subscribe in the past. This can only be achived by retrieving a list of all topics for the certain user from database. Then a method inside onTokenRefresh() can re subscribe all topics for this user on his new device. Otherwise the user has to do this manual by hisself, what he didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with Redis and LUA-Scripting in combination with lists, this guarantees me fast access as well as User can see for every group/news feed if he subscribed it or not (like Facebook). When User logs into a new device, he'll re subscribed for all topics he was.