# Is there a way to delete Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Topics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Possible Duplicate:
[How to delete a topic from Firebase Console? (FCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646157/how-to-delete-a-topic-from-firebase-console-fcm)

I have a few questions regarding FCM topics. From what is listed in the docs, an application is limited to only have 2,000 topics, with each topic may have unlimited number of subscribers. Now, my questions:

1. Is there a way to look at what topics that our project has?
2. Is there a way to delete topics? Because I'm afraid that my project will eventually hit the 2,000 limit. It would be convenient if there is a way to delete topics, such as if a topic has no subscribers, or that a topic has been inactive for a certain time.

There is a possible duplicate question in the link above, but I want to get more opinions from the community as that one seems to be an assumption.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Nope. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874606/how-to-get-all-topics-list-of-firebase-through-api?noredirect=1, 2. Nope. See the link you gave yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646157/how-to-delete-a-topic-from-firebase-console-fcm As said there: topics are auto-deleted when there are no more subscribers.

Comment: Hope this helps,

I think if you don't have subscribers to a topic it automatically gets deleted. Try unsubscribing all from the topic you want to remove. You can get the list of topics from the firebase console(Grow -> Cloud Messaging -> New notification -> Target -> Topics)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @FrankvanPuffelen. Apparently I've also asked in the Google Forums and found a clear answer. It turns out that Firebase is limited **only to 2,000 topics per application instance, not per project**. Therefore, my fear is no longer relevant.